# Passing Container.Eval to (Html.ReaderPartial) inside ASP.NET Repeater Control

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, repeater, htmlextensions

I am trying to pass Eval to Html.RenderPartial inside ASP.NET Repeater but it does not work can any one help?

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <% Html.RenderPartial("UserControl1",Eval("Title")); %>
            </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

by the way I know that I can do it in other ways but I want to know if it is doable or not.

Comment: I know you can compbine WinForms with MVC... But man... I wouldn't recommend it. You're going to end up in a place you don't want to be. Maybe try putting your RenderPartial inside <%# %> statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

is the same as  in that it expects an expression that returns a string, so to get this compiling you have to call a method that calls Html.RenderPartial(), then returns an empty string:

```
<%
protected string RenderControl(object dataItem) 
{
    Html.RenderPartial("UserControl1", ((MyType) dataItem).Title);
    return "";
}
%>

... <%# RenderControl(Container.DataItem) %> ...
```

I would just use foreach though - mixing WebForms data-binding and MVC partial rendering is unpredictable, at best:

```
<% foreach (MyObject o in data) { Html.RenderPartial("UserControl1", o.Title); } %>
```

Don't make life any harder than it needs to be...

Comment: Every thing is easy but <code><% Html.RenderPartial("UserControl1", o.Title);%></code> is making it hard it is different from other html extentions Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your RenderPartial inside `<%# %>` statement like:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Html.RenderPartial("UserControl1",Eval("Title")); %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I got this compilation exception:
CS1026: ) expected
I test it before it wont work 
thanks again...